# Static object defined in base should be different for child classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I have a base class `BaseClass` which has a Texture or bitmap. Two classes derive from it, lets say `AChild` and `BChild`. Each of child class set the Texture. Now Texture will be remain same for each child class. I don't want multiple variables of Texture for objects of each child class. I want it to be singleton.

Here is some code.

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public Texture TextureImage { get; set; }
    public Texture LoadTexture(string path)
    {
         return some texture using path,
    }
}

class AChild : BaseClass
{
    AChild()
    {
         if (TextureImage == null)
             TextureImage = LoadTexture(PathToImageA);
    }
}

class BChild : BaseClass
{
    BChild()
    {
         if (TextureImage == null)
             TextureImage = LoadTexture(PathToImageB);
    }
}

Main()
{
     var aOne = new AChild();
     var aTwo = new AChild();

     var bOne = new BChild();
     var bTwo = new BChild();

}
```

Now here you see that whenever I make object of `AChild` or `BChild` a new texture is created. What I want to achieve is that whenever first child (aOne) of AChild is created TextureImage should be initialized, and when another object is created (aTwo) it uses the texture created by first child.

I tried to make TextureImage static in base class, but after that bOne texture was the one which aOne created.

I am sure this is possible what I want, but question is how?

Comment: It sounds like you need to make an override in the child classes or make the base an interface and implement the static in the child classes.

Comment: @crashmstr can you help me with the code, I am trying to do this but failed.

Comment: Simply removing the test for == null in the AChild class and making the TextureObject static should work. BChild still test for null.

Comment: @Steve he wants all `AChild` to have a `TextureImage` with `PathToImageA` and all `BChild` to have a *different* one with `PathToImageB`.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by *crashmstr* comment and a good night sleep i came up with this solution

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AChild a1 = new AChild();
        Console.WriteLine(a1.TextureImage.Path);
        BChild b = new BChild();
        Console.WriteLine(b.TextureImage.Path);
        AChild a2 = new AChild();
        Console.WriteLine(a2.TextureImage.Path);
    }
}

public class Texture
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Texture> TextureImageCache { get; set; }

    static BaseClass()
    {
        TextureImageCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Texture>();
    }

    public virtual Texture TextureImage
    {
        get
        {
            return TextureImageCache.GetOrAdd(
                this.GetType(),
                t => this.LoadTexture(this.TexturePath));
        }
    }

    public Texture LoadTexture(string path)
    {
        return new Texture { Path = path };
    }

    public abstract string TexturePath { get; }
}

public class AChild : BaseClass
{

    public override string TexturePath
    {
        get { return "iamgeA"; }
    }
}

public class BChild : BaseClass
{

    public override string TexturePath
    {
        get { return "imageB"; }
    }
}
```

Some highlights:

- A ConcurrentDictionary which loads the texture only when first needed (lazy-loaded)
- The base class only makes the derived classes implement the `Path` property.
- I strongly believe this is an elegant and robust solution which removes the need to directly manipulate the `type` in derived classes and it scales very easily to new derived classes

Comment: With this method, I would probably "hide" the `Dictionary` and still have `TextureImage` return a `Texture`.

Comment: @Faisal: Did this work? If so, please upvote and accept the answer; otherwise tell me what could be changed

Answer (score 0):

I reworked the answer to use an abstract property & overrides in AChild & BChild.

Make the `TextureImage` property in the `BaseClass` `abstract`.  Then, override the abstract property in `AChild` & `BChild`:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract Texture TextureImage { get; }
    private Texture _TextureImage;
}

class AChild : BaseClass
{
    public override Texture TextureImage {
        get {
          if ( _TextureImage == null )
              _TextureImage = LoadTexture(PathToImageA);
          return _TextureImage;
        }
    }
}

class BChild : BaseClass
{
    public override Texture TextureImage {
        get {
          if ( _TextureImage == null )
              _TextureImage = LoadTexture(PathToImageB);
          return _TextureImage;
        }
    }
}

Main()
{
     var aOne = new AChild();
     var aTwo = new AChild();

     var bOne = new BChild();
     var bTwo = new BChild();

}
```

Comment: It didn't work. BChild.TextureImage was not null when first child was created,

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but I think this will do what you want.
In each child class, have a private `Texture` and [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) the base class's `TextureImage` to use the child class's own static version.

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public static Texture TextureImage { get; set; }
    public Texture LoadTexture(string path)
    {
         //return some texture using path,
    }
}

class AChild : BaseClass
{
    private static Texture TextureImageA { get; set; }
    public override Texture TextureImage 
    {
        get { return TextureImageA; }
        set { TextureImageA = value; }
    }

    AChild()
    {
         if (TextureImage == null)
             TextureImage = LoadTexture(PathToImageA);
    }
}

class BChild : BaseClass
{
    private static Texture TextureImageB { get; set; }
    public override Texture TextureImage 
    {
        get { return TextureImageB; }
        set { TextureImageB = value; }
    }

    BChild()
    {
         if (TextureImage == null)
             TextureImage = LoadTexture(PathToImageB);
    }
}
```